# Python/JSON: How to Resolve UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, json

I have been trying to learn Python recently and following along with the book, *[Python for Data Analysis](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do)* and using Python 2.7 with Canopy.  In the book, they provided a link to some [raw data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pydata/pydata-book/master/ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt) which I saved and assigned to a `path` variable.  After trying to convert the text file to a list of dictionaries using JSON:

```
records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]
```

I received the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b1e0b494454a> in <module>()
----> 1 records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]

C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-    x86_64\lib\json\__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int,     parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    336             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    337             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 338         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    339     if cls is None:
    340         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-    x86_64\lib\json\decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    363 
    364         """
--> 365         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    366         end = _w(s, end).end()
    367         if end != len(s):

C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\json\decoder.pyc in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    379         """
    380         try:
--> 381             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    382         except StopIteration:
    383             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 6: invalid start byte
```

The weird thing is that this worked on a different computer, which I thought was using the same version of Python.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JSON data is not UTF-8 encoded, it appears. Are you 100% certain it is the same data you are decoding?

Comment: The "default" encoding that Python will try to use can vary from one computer to the next depending on that system's locale settings, even if the same version of Python is used. This behavior is intentional.

Comment: @SLawson: this has nothing to do with default (file) encodings. This is Python 2, where no decoding of file data takes place. The `json` module does decode, because the JSON standard specifies a (limited) number of encodings that are acceptable.

Comment: @SLawson: in Python 3, the `open()` call without explicit `encoding` parameter will indeed use the system locale to determine a default codec, but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: The data is definitely the same, maybe I'm wrong about the other computer's Python version though.

Comment: Is there some way I can determine what type of encoding the text file is using?

Comment: The only difference I can think of about the data is that on the other computer I copied the text into vi and on this one I copied it into a txt file.

Comment: @user2899059: then you cannot be sure the file contents are the same. You copied text, you say? How did you copy it, where from?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: In both cases I copied it straight from the link I provided.

Comment: @user2899059: but did you use your browser to select the data? Why not just save the file *directly to disk* instead? That data indeed contains UTF-8 bytes (encoding a [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://codepoints.net/U+2019).

Comment: @MartijnPieters My mistake. I didn't realize that Python 2's `open()` and the JSON module's use of `open()` handle decoding differently than the Python3 `open()`. I thought they were  the same. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in question contains one [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://codepoints.net/U+2019) character, encoded to UTF-8. But you used copy-and-paste to save the data rather than save the text straight to disk.

In doing so, somewhere along the way the data was decoded, then encoded again, to Windows Codepage 1252:

```
>>> u'\u2019'.encode('cp1252')
'\x92'
```

In other words, your data file is **not the same**. It probably contains the same data but using a different encoding.

The JSON standard states data needs to be [encoded to UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-8.1), with UTF-8 being the default, and that is what the Python `json` module will use if you don't give it an encoding. Because you are feeding it CP-1252 data instead, the decoding fails.